# Spark-sql parquet compression settings seem to be not working

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have set compression settings in `SparkConf` as follows:

`sparkConf.set("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "SNAPPY")`

and also after 'SparkSession' creation as follows:

```
 val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .config(sparkConf)
    .config("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "GZIP") //SNAPPY
    .config("spark.io.compression.codec", "org.apache.spark.io.LZ4CompressionCodec")
```

However, I see following in executor stdout:

```
Mar 16, 2019 10:34:16 AM INFO: parquet.hadoop.codec.CodecConfig: Compression set to false
Mar 16, 2019 10:34:16 AM INFO: parquet.hadoop.codec.CodecConfig: Compression: UNCOMPRESSED
Mar 16, 2019 10:34:16 AM INFO: parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat: Parquet block size to 134217728
Mar 16, 2019 10:34:16 AM INFO: parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat: Parquet page size to 1048576
Mar 16, 2019 10:34:16 AM INFO: parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat: Parquet dictionary page size to 1048576
Mar 16, 2019 10:34:16 AM INFO: parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat: Dictionary is on
Mar 16, 2019 10:34:16 AM INFO: parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat: Validation is off
Mar 16, 2019 10:34:16 AM INFO: parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat: Writer version is: PARQUET_1_0
Mar 16, 2019 10:34:17 AM INFO: parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter: Flushing mem columnStore to file. allocated memory: 0
```

Concerning output is :

```
Mar 16, 2019 10:34:16 AM INFO: parquet.hadoop.codec.CodecConfig: Compression set to false
Mar 16, 2019 10:34:16 AM INFO: parquet.hadoop.codec.CodecConfig: Compression: UNCOMPRESSED
```

Does this mean spark is writing uncompressed data to parquet? If not how do I verify? Is there a way to view parquet metadata?

Comment: Check if small case value solves the problem "snappy" or "gzip"

Comment: that didn't help

Comment: We use mapr distribution of spark and hadoop. Looks like compression is set at maprfs level. I can verify it via `hadoop mfs -ls ` that each file is compressed with LZ4. They don't have `gzip` or `snappy` as options. I have to check with them.